# Unable to pause Video when closing a modal

Tags: javascript, html, video, pause

I realise this has been asked before and for that, I apologise but as it stands I can't get a pop up modal to stop playing a video when the close button is pressed.

Any help would obviously be grand.

Thank you!

HTML:

```
    <div class="converseVideo">
        <div class=textAnchor>
            <h3 class=stickyConverseText>I was lost for language too</h3>
        </div>
            <video autoplay muted loop class="myVideo converseVideoContainer">
                <source src="Media/converse.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>    
                <button onclick="toggleConversePopUp()" class="playButton conversePlayButton"> 
                  <img src="Media/playIcon.jpg" title="Play Icon">
                </button>
            <h2 class=videoTagsLeft>Converse</h2>
        </div>

    <div class="videoPopUp" id="popup-1">
        <video class="conversePopUp" id="myVideo" controls>
            <source src="Media/converse.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <button class="closeButton" onclick="toggleConversePopUp()" >&times;</button>
    </div>
```

and this is the JS:

```
   let modalOpen = false; // Default to closed

    function openModal() {
      setModal(true);
    }

    function closeModal() {
      setModal(false);
    }

    function toggleModal() {
      setModal(!modalOpen);
    }

    function setModal(value) {
      modalOpen = value;
      document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active", value);
    }

    function pauseMedia() {
      document.querySelector('video').pause()
    }

    function playMedia() {}



    function toggleConversePopUp(){
        document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was actually quite simple. I think I needed to have JQuery which I hadn't set up and then it was a relatively simple piece of JS which is below.... for anyone that stumbles across this and has a similar issue!

```
function toggleConversePopUp(){
    document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
    if($('.active').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('myVideo').pause();
    }
}
```